# How to make collectionViewLayout to dynamically change height and width of cell?

Tags: swift, xcode

Am trying to make Collection View with a specific layout like on the image below

[image: Layout]

So some cell is two rows by two columns, and some are one by one

If anybody has some tutorial or hint please share.

EDIT - This is my code for Custom Layout class

```
protocol CustomLayoutDelegate: class {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, sizeForCellAtIndexPath indexPath:IndexPath) -> CGSize
}

class CustomLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    weak var delegate: CustomLayoutDelegate!

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        let layoutAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)
        var cnt: CGFloat = 0
        var cols: CGFloat = 0
        var rows: CGFloat = 0

        layoutAttributes?.forEach({ (attributes) in
            guard let cv = collectionView else { return }
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: attributes.indexPath.item, section: 0)
            let cellSize = delegate.collectionView(cv, sizeForCellAtIndexPath: indexPath)

            attributes.frame = CGRect(x: cellSize.width * (cols), y: cellSize.height * rows, width: cellSize.width, height: cellSize.height)
            print(cnt, cols, rows)

            cnt += 1
            cols = cols < 2 ? (cols + 1) : 0

            if Int(cnt.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 3)) == 0 {
                rows += 1
            }

        })

        return layoutAttributes
    }

    override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Add the code that you have already tried.

Comment: that is not an easy layout and you'll never get it with standard `UICollectionViewLayout`. You need to subclass it and work from there

Comment: I forgot to paste my class for custom layout

Comment: Not sure whether CollectionView suits for this, But you can achieve the same via TableView with different rows.

Comment: @HeshanSandeepa relay? I always prefer CollectionView over TableView. How this will be done in TableView, did you have some sample? Am planning to make two iterations, in one map the positions and w/h, and in second to a position on the right place...